# PostgreSQL and Point in Time Recovery

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, recovery

I was reading through this:  http://www.postgresql.org/about/

And I saw this:

> An enterprise class database,
>   PostgreSQL boasts sophisticated
>   features such as ... **point in time**
>   **recovery**

I need some light shed on this subject and its features and examples of it in action or share their own performance experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consult [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/backup.html).

I think that you will want to read mostly part "24.4. Warm Standby Servers for High Availability" - but what is written there is based on information from "24.3. Continuous Archiving and Point-In-Time Recovery (PITR)" so you might want to read it first.

To summarize:

- pitr lets you do continuous backup with very low performance impact.
- this backup is incremental
- it can be restored to any given point in time (hence the name)
- using pitr you can also setup warm standby server